# Creates a sequence of all subsets as a list of text strings

Tags: python, function, substring

Need help creating a function  that subsets a list. This is my code so far .

```
def substrings(txt):
    """Creates the sequence of all subsets as a list of text strings"""

    for i in range(len(txt), len(txt) + 1):
        for a in itertools.combinations( "a,b,c,d,e", 1):
            yield functools.reduce(lambda i, a: i+a ,txt)

# Main program (does not change):
import functools, itertools

for sub in substrings('abcde'):
    print(sub, end=' ')
```

The code should return

```
a b c d e ab ac ad ae bc bd be cd ce de abc abd abe acd ace ade bcd bce bde cde abcd abce abde acde bcde abcde
```

But I keep getting

```
abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde
```

Answer (score 1):

Your range is incorrect, and also you seem to have hardcoded the input (`abcde`) in your function instead of using `txt`. Try this:

```
def substrings(txt):
    """Creates the sequence of all subsets as a list of text strings"""

    for i in range(1, len(txt) + 1):
        for a in itertools.combinations(txt, i):
            yield "".join(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

- You should be looping from 1 to the length of `txt`.
- The argument to `itertools.combinations()` should be `txt`, not a hard-coded string (which also shouldn't contain `,`), and the combination size should be `i`, not 1.
- Use `''.join()` to convert the combination to a string, not `functools.reduce()`. And if you do use `reduce()`, the argument should be `a`, not `txt`. That's why you keep getting the whole string, not the subsets.

In general, if you have a `for` loop and never use the iteration variable, something is usually wrong.

```
# Main program (does not change):
import itertools

def substrings(txt):
    """Creates the sequence of all subsets as a list of text strings"""

    for i in range(1, len(txt) + 1):
        for a in itertools.combinations(txt, i):
            yield ''.join(a)

for sub in substrings('abcde'):
    print(sub, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

A slick way to do this is, which doesn't require using any higher level modules, is using binary logic:

```
def substrings(inp):
    for i in range(1, 2 ** len(inp)):
        elem = ""
        for j in range(len(inp)):
            if ((1 << j) & i) > 0:
                elem += inp[j]
        yield elem


inp = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print([x for x in substrings(inp)])
```

Result:

```
 ['a', 'b', 'ab', 'c', 'ac', 'bc', 'abc', 'd', 'ad', 'bd', 'abd', 'cd', 'acd', 'bcd', 'abcd', 'e', 'ae', 'be', 'abe', 'ce', 'ace', 'bce', 'abce', 'de', 'ade', 'bde', 'abde', 'cde', 'acde', 'bcde', 'abcde']
```

Here, we iterate over all of the numbers between 1 and 2 raised to the length of the input list.  This produces a bitfield, where  every combination of bits represents a different combination of the input strings in the list.  For example, the last number, `2**<len>`, is a number that has a `1` in every bit position, representing the set with all input elements included.

Comment: He wants a generator, not a list. Presumably because the number of subsets can become very large.

Comment: You're essentially re-implementing `combinations()`. That's not very pythonic, we use libraries when they're available.

Comment: But I'm not.  If `combinations()` could be called just once, what you say would be true.  As it is, you need to call `combinations()` multiple times.  I don't mind the solution that uses `combinations()`, but once you have to add your own logic, I think my version is simpler.  It may not be "better', but I still see it as a viable alternative.  Also, it demonstrates an idea that can be used more generally, in situations where `combinations()` wouldn't give you the result you wanted.  It's a way of iterating over every combination of some things in a very concise way.

Comment: I see your point. In the loop we call it once for each length, you use one algorithm for all the lengths.

Comment: This idea came from something I did recently where we needed to build a bunch of vectors.  In that case, we were operating on numeric arrays, not lists.  I just saw that this idea was applicable to the question, so I grabbed it and adapted it.  If I'd been starting from scratch, maybe I'd have used something from `collections` as well.